# How to move files in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xml, laravel, axios

I have application where by I am using laravel as my backend to make APIs and I am using react as my front end. So in my react front end I  managed to get file which is in .txt by using axios and process that file and save it into database. Now it comes that after processing that file then it should be deleted on previous directory and moved to other directory, so my question is how can I move that file?

Here is my code:

```
 axios
      .get("docuin/incoming.xml", {
        "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
      })
      .then((response) => {
        var xml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(response.data);
        var from = xml.getElementsByTagName("ID")[0].value;
        //from here i can send to DB using post axios,after sucessful sent now it should move into "docout/outgoing.xml"

});
```

I have tried to send it via axios post but brings errors.